# How to pass Data From Javascript To Android WebView in this case?

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Main();

}
public void Main()
{
    _linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    _webview = new WebView(this);
    _linearLayout.addView(_webview, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    setContentView(_linearLayout);

    _webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    _webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    _webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    _webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    _webview.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Question");
    _webview.loadData(GetHTML(), "text/html", "utf-8");


}

public String GetHTML()
{   
    String HTML = ""
        + "<HTML>"
        + "<HEAD>"
        + "<TITLE>Radio Button onClick Handler</TITLE>"
        + "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\"JavaScript\">"
        +"function function1(colors) {" 
        +"var col = (colors.options[colors.selectedIndex].value);"
        +" if (col) {"
        +"  document.bgColor = col;"

        +"   } "
        +"</script>"
        + "</HEAD>"
        + "<BODY>"
        +"<form>"
        +"<b> Hello </b>"
        //+"<select name=\"colors\" onChange=\"window.Question.function1(this);\">"
        +"<select name=\"colors\" onChange=\"window.Question.OnJsClick_SelectedItem(' string value');\">"
           +"<option value=\"white\" selected>White</option>"
           + "<option value=\"cyan\">Cyan</option>"
           + "<option value=\"ivory\">Ivory</option>"
           + "<option id=\"myO\" value=\"blue\">Blue</option>"

        +"</select>"
        +"</form>"
        + "</BODY>"
        + "</HTML>";

    return HTML;
}

public void OnJsClick_SelectedItem(final String str)
{
    mHandler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        //@Override
        public void run()
        {
            getValue(str);
        }
    });
}

public String getValue(String str)
{
    _webview.loadUrl("javascript:function1(colors)");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Under getValue " + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return str;

}
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
<select name="colors"
    onChange="Question.OnJsClick_SelectedItem(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)">
```

Answer (score 5):

You can store the code as a HTML page in assets folder and use the load URL method to the webview to show the webpage.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Edits according to the comment

**Enabling JavaScript**

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

**here's some HTML and JavaScript that creates a toast message using the new interface when the user clicks a button**

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

**Add this in your Java code**

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's fine I can load HTML Page from asset folder and load via loadURL. Here my problem is I want to get the selected value of combo box inside Toast.Suppose user select ivory color then my toast print ivory selected. Can u help me please?? @Rishabh

Comment: I am able to load HTML inside webview but I want to pass the selected value (combo box selected value written in javascript) to java code

Comment: try the editted code out it will enable integrating java code into javascript, HTML.
And accept if it works

Comment: Just call a function in the javascript and pass the value to it .