# Android post data to a form on website

Tags: android, http, post

I can't find a proper way to post some data in a form on website. I have an url of website. I know how to establish connection in android, but how to post data in a form on this page?

Web page has next form:

```
<form method="get" action="">
        <div id="charname">
    // Login Field
            <input type="text" name="charname" value="">
              </div>
      //Password Field
          <input type="text" value="" name="s_pair" id="code_input">
          <br>
          // Action Button
          <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="vote" id="check_vote_form" disabled="disabled"></div>
      </form>
```

Is it possible to do in Android?

Comment: Use a library such as [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: @OmarAflak could you share some links \ give me more details?

Comment: Check the retrofit link in my first comment. The documentation is pretty clear

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to send data to and from webView and Android Native if that is what you are asking. Check this post [How to pass Data From Javascript To Android WebView in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357191/how-to-pass-data-from-javascript-to-android-webview-in-this-case) they show a few good examples. You have to declare your JS methods and wrap the Android code that will execute and so on.